# Не отправляет в БД через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Вот такой код у меня есть:
HTML

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="set_coment">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="user" id="user" />
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="text" id="text" />
  <button type="button" id="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector("#send").onclick = function () {
  if (document.querySelector("#user") == "") {
    alert("USER!");
  }
  else if (document.querySelector("#text") == "") {
    alert("TEXT!");
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector("#set_coment").submit();
  }
}
```

PHP

```
$connect = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "DaniilSkLi", "666l666", "PHP");
$user = $_POST["user"];
$text = $_POST["text"];
$date = date(Y . "-" . m . "-" . d);
echo $user . ":" . $text . ":" . $date;
$date = date(d . "-" . m . "-" . Y);
if ($user != "" && $text != "") {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO coment (`user`, `date`, `text`) VALUES ($user, $date, $text)";
  echo "<br />" . substr($sql, 0, 0);
  if ($connect->query($sql) == true) {
    echo "Отправлено!";
  }
  else {
    echo "При отправке вознивкла неизвестная ошибка, попробуйте еще раз позже.";
  }
}
```

Должно отправлять данные в инпутах в БД, оно так и делает только когда в инпутах написаны числа, а если буквы будь то английские или русские - нет ошибки но не отправляется и выводит то что я ввел тут

```
echo "При отправке вознивкла неизвестная ошибка, попробуйте еще раз позже.";
```

В чем проблема? Если ввести буквы напрямую без переменных то все равботает.

Comment: Про кавычки подумайте. А затем про подготовленные выражения.

Comment: Да, вы были правы, я поставил еще раз кавычки двойные но уже их экранировал через \ а не делал так: (' . "$name" . ',' . и т.д. сделал так: $sql = "INSERT INTO coment (`user`, `date`, `text`) VALUES (\"$user\", \"$date\", \"$text\")"; и все заработало

Comment: А если у вас в переменной $text будут кавычки? Смешно будет выглядеть. Ещё раз перечитайте комментарий @u_mulder

Comment: типо пользователь может ввести в коментарий кавычи?